# having trouble with jquery.post() and php curl

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I made a script to post comments on a page. I have used PHP curl and it works but I need to use AJAX so the page doesn't reload. When i use jQuery `.post()` the response says:

> method not allowed use post or get.

This is my code:

```
include("userinfo.php");
if ($_POST['action'] === 'postcomment'){
    $imageid = $_POST['imageid'];
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:", "Api-Key: ".$apikey));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.myphotodiary.com/users/".$user."/images /".$imageid."/comments.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("text" => $text));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
$("form.imagecommentform").live("submit",function(e){
    $text = $(this).find(".text");
    $username = $(this).find(".username");
    $imageid = $(this).find(".imageid");
    $.post("inc/imagecomment.php",{
        immageid: $imageid.val(),
        username: $username.val(),
        text: $text.val()
        action: "postcomment"
    }, function(html) {
        $(this).find($(".msg")).empty();
        $(this).find($(".msg")).html(html);
    }, "json");
    return false;
});
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it by using `$.ajax()` instead of `.post()`.